# Как использовать в data атрибуте имя с дефисом через dataset?

Tags: javascript

Нужно получить значение атрибута `data-items-number` через `dataset`

Значение постоянно обновляется, в том числе динамический сам блок `<div class="counts">...</div>`

Есть способ получать через `getAttribute`, но не уверен что будет работать стабильно при больших объемах данных и массовых изменениях

```js
document.addEventListener('click',function(e) {
  if (e.target.closest('.counts .dropdown > div')) {
    console.log(e.target.dataset['items-number']);
  }
  if (e.target.closest('.counts2 .dropdown > div')) {
    console.log(e.target);
    console.log(e.target.dataset.itemsNumber);
  }
});
```

```css
.dropdown > div {
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: #06f;
  border: 1px solid #06f;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="counts">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div data-items-number="1">Пример</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="counts2">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <div data-itemsNumber="1">Пример 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правило такое: что имена в самом html пишутся через дефис, а в JS пишутся через camelCase, не считая префикс `data-`

То есть в html атрибут `data-items-number`, а в *JS* будет обращение таким: `dataset.itemsNumber`

Comment: Подгружаю динамические html данные через стороний api, там почему то через дефис дают эти атрибуты, видимо кто то что то не учел)

Comment: кстати `camelCase` у меня не работает, посмотрел через `e.target` все символы в нижнем регистре, пишу `data-itemsNumber` он выводит `data-itemsnumber` Добавил в вопрос пример

Comment: ...Куда выводит?  "*пишу data-itemsNumber*" --- куда пишешь? зачем ты **так** пишешь?

Comment: а как правильно написать?

Comment: В ответе написано как и где правильно писать.

Comment: Спасибо, понял в чем дело) что то путаница какая то с этими авто изменениями